# Can I make it so when I select in a select box the title is updated using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<select name="TopicID" id="TopicID">
  <option value="00">XX</option>
  <option value="02">YY</option>
</select>
```

How can I make it so that when a user selects a new value such as "YY" that the title of the select gets updated like this:

```
<select title="YY" name="TopicID" id="TopicID">
  <option value="00">XX</option>
  <option value="02">YY</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event and update the `title` attribute:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $(this).attr("title", $("option:selected", this).text());
});
```

Note that the code above uses [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead of [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to emphasize we're creating or updating an HTML attribute rather than a DOM property. That is only a matter of preference, using `prop()` would result in the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#TopicID").on("change", function() {
    var select = $(this);
    select.attr("title", select.find(":selected").text());
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/TVT4C/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#TopicID').change(function () {
    $(this).attr('title', $('#TopicID option[value="' + this.value + '"]').text());
});
```

Check it live http://jsfiddle.net/MAhmadZ/PpjwT/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
$('#TopicID').change(function() {
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr('title', selectedItem);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its not jquery but should do. Add the first line of following code to your control and 
add the later function in your script

```
onchange="SetTitle(this,this.value);"
function SetTitle(cntrl,val)
{
cntrl.setAttribut("title",val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var newtitle=$('#TopicID').val();

$('#TopicID').attr('title',newtitle);`